# Make Select One Menu primefaces overlayed

Tags: html, css, primefaces

The `<p:menu/>` component in Primefaces allows to overlay the Menu next to an element but it generates a `<div>` with `<ul>`as a child. I am wondering if it is at all possible to get the overlaying but using `<p:selectOneMenu/>`component; which generates a `<div> > <select>` element in the DOM.

I have a column which repeats 4 rows in this case. Every row has three elements: a div, a label and the Select One Menu. What I want is to be able to overlay this select menu. I tried to change the values of `visibility: hidden`  but the element still occupies that space.

```
<div class="v-model-container-column">
            <p:repeat value="#{yAxis}" var="y" varStatus="varStatusY">
             <div class="v-model-container-row">   
                <div class="v-model-rhombus v-model-rightV">

                </div>
                <p:outputLabel id="testLevelLabel" value="#{y.name}" styleClass="v-model-label"/>
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{selectionMap[y]}"
                                 converter="viewResourceConverter"
                                 onchange="vModel.select(this)" >
                    <f:selectItems value="#{xAxis}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </div>
            </p:repeat>
        </div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone

Comment: And see if the `appendTo` attribute can help

Comment: Thank you @Kukeltje. That really helped a lot.

Comment: Which of the two comments? So I can mark it as duplicate

Comment: The first one, I used a workaround keeping the selectOneMenu and using jQuery selectors to manipulate DOM elements so it can be clicked.

Comment: Then I have honestly no clue what your real problem is... I suspect you work around something that might be solved with the second comment